# Java generic to Kotlin generic. Return generic from method

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

Trying to convert a project from Java to Kotlin.

I got stuck on a method that returns ObservableTransformer from RXJava 2

Java

```
protected <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> onNetworkError() {
    return observable -> observable
            .doOnError(throwable -> networkError.setValue(throwable));
}
```

Converting this using intellij ide throws an error.

Java to Kotlin using ide

```
protected fun <T> onNetworkError(): ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    return { observable ->
        observable
                .doOnError({ throwable -> networkError.setValue(throwable) })
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to convert the above Java code to Kotlin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is returning a function which accepts `observable` of unknown type and returns an `Observable` object.

The lambda expression you need should be like this:

```
protected fun <T> onNetworkError(): ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    return ObservableTransformer { observable ->
        observable
                .doOnError({ throwable -> networkError.setValue(throwable) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to BakaWaii's response from above, you can further simplify the code as follows:

```
protected fun <T> onNetworkError(): ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    return ObservableTransformer {
        it.doOnError { networkError.setValue(it) }
    }
}
```

However, having two different `it`s might be confusing, so you might want to leave one of them as an explicit parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I always looking for ways to simplify the code. I marked BakaWaii as correct answer as he was first to write.